# How to Group by with sum of multi row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. `Ticket` and `TicketBasket` as following image.
[image: Ticket and TicketBasket releationship]

I want to select somthings like this:
|**tId**|**tDate**|**customerName**|**expDate**|**tax**|**total**|
|1  |xxx |xxx      |xxx  |2 |25 |
|2  |xxx |xxx      |xxx  |2 |20 |
|3  |xxx |xxx      |xxx  |2 |15 |

because of my sql command, the result has iteration with tId because each Ticket can have multi Items in it's basket.
my sql code is :

```
SELECT distinct Ticket.tId,dbo.ToCustomeDate(Ticket.tDate) 'tDate',
     Ticket.customerName,dbo.ToCustomeDate(isnull(Ticket.expDate,Ticket.tDate)) 'expDate',
      Ticket.tax,

    (
        (((TicketBasket.gamePrice*TicketBasket.gameCount)-
        (((TicketBasket.gamePrice * TicketBasket.gameCount)*TicketBasket.offPrice)/100))+
        (((TicketBasket.gamePrice * TicketBasket.gameCount)-
        (((TicketBasket.gamePrice * TicketBasket.gameCount)*TicketBasket.offPrice)/100))* (Ticket.tax)/100))

    ) AS total
    FROM   Ticket right JOIN TicketBasket
    ON Ticket.tId = TicketBasket.tId
```

but the result is 
|**tId**|**tDate**|**customerName**|**expDate**|**tax**|**total**|
|1  |xxx |xxx      |xxx  |2 |10 |
|1  |xxx |xxx      |xxx  |2 |10 |
|1  |xxx |xxx      |xxx  |2 |5   |
|2  |xxx |xxx      |xxx  |2 |10 |
|2  |xxx |xxx      |xxx  |2 |10 |
|3  |xxx |xxx      |xxx  |2 |10 |
|3  |xxx |xxx      |xxx  |2 |5   |

I can handle this with `cursor` but I know it's a heavy load to execute the select query, so thanks for other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work..based on your query's output:

```
Select 
iq.tld, iq.tDate, iq.customerName, iq.expDate,iq.tax,
SUM(total) as newTotal
from
(
SELECT distinct Ticket.tId,dbo.ToCustomeDate(Ticket.tDate) 'tDate',
     Ticket.customerName,dbo.ToCustomeDate(isnull(Ticket.expDate,Ticket.tDate)) 'expDate',
      Ticket.tax,

    (
        (((TicketBasket.gamePrice*TicketBasket.gameCount)-
        (((TicketBasket.gamePrice * TicketBasket.gameCount)*TicketBasket.offPrice)/100))+
        (((TicketBasket.gamePrice * TicketBasket.gameCount)-
        (((TicketBasket.gamePrice * TicketBasket.gameCount)*TicketBasket.offPrice)/100))* (Ticket.tax)/100))

    ) AS total
    FROM   Ticket right JOIN TicketBasket
    ON Ticket.tId = TicketBasket.tId
)iq
group by iq.tld, iq.tDate, iq.customerName, iq.expDate,iq.tax
```